# Is it possible to always use only POST requests?

Tags: php, post, get, request

Beside the situation we do request by direct url typing.

Just assuming only actions from being already on website. All anchors, forms, all actions we need or we want to have on website.

Selectings someone's profile acc, listing all posts of this person.
Just every action we need or want.

Is it possible to always use only POST requests? To ommit completly GET?

Comment: Clicking on a link sends a `GET` request.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  ASP.NET WebForms has generally always done this by default with their "postback" model.  *Why* someone would do this is beyond me, and it's going to involve some coding to make it happen (in particular to replace links with form posts, etc.).  But you're essentially asking if it's possible to make POST requests at all, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` requests are used extensively:

- Clicking on an anchor
- Loading external Javascript in `<script>` tags
- Loading `<img>` tags
- Loading CSS in `<link>` tags
- Loading images referenced in `url(...)` styles

It's probably possible to write Javascript that replaces all these normal actions, and some frameworks may do so for some of them. Although overriding the CSS `url(...)` stuff seems like it would be tricky.

However, if you replace them with Javascript, it has to use `XMLHttpRequest` (i.e. AJAX), and then it would run into restrictions due to the same-origin policy.